# Update Statement Issues with Apache Ignite(2.13.0) + Java Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, ignite

We are facing issues while updating tables having column with datatype timestamp.

Insert and Update works fine if we use ignite repository for both.
Insert or Update works fine if we use native queries for both.
Insert via Ignite repository and update via native queries results in an below error

````
class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Invalid flag value: 32
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.builder.BinaryBuilderReader.parseValue(BinaryBuilderReader.java:863)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.builder.BinaryObjectBuilderImpl.serializeTo(BinaryObjectBuilderImpl.java:290)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.builder.BinaryBuilderSerializer.writeValue(BinaryBuilderSerializer.java:103)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.builder.BinaryBuilderSerializer.writeValue(BinaryBuilderSerializer.java:56)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.builder.BinaryObjectBuilderImpl.serializeTo(BinaryObjectBuilderImpl.java:297)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.builder.BinaryBuilderSerializer.writeValue(BinaryBuilderSerializer.java:103)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.builder.BinaryBuilderSerializer.writeValue(BinaryBuilderSerializer.java:56)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.builder.BinaryObjectBuilderImpl.serializeTo(BinaryObjectBuilderImpl.java:297)
    ```
````

Answer (score 1):

If you can post example code, this would make a good bug report.

https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/876a2ca190dbd88f42bc7acecff8b7783ce7ce54/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/internal/binary/builder/BinaryBuilderReader.java#L515